# Volley BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: problem on slow network

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am using volley to hit api. On slow network i get the above error. The weird part is that if i hit the url on browser on the same network it returns with the required response.

What could be the problem and how can i optimise volley to work on slow network?

Answer (score 0):

Add this code into your code. I hope it helps.

```
jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(0,
                        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

            queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```